# Visual express c++ with C++11 and threads support

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I am currently using Visual Express C++ (2010) for my project, but I am looking at features in C++11 (thread support). This does not seem to be supported in Express 2010.

From my research so far it looks like I will need Visual Express C++ 2012 version to get support for this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)?

Cite from this page:

> > In VC11, we intend to completely support the C++11 Standard Library, modulo not-yet-implemented compiler features.  (Additionally, VC11
> >     won't completely implement the C99 Standard Library, which has been
> >     incorporated by reference into the C++11 Standard Library.  Note that
> >     VC10 and VC11 already have .)  Here's a non-exhaustive list
> >     of the changes we're making:
>
> New headers:

```
   <atomic>, <chrono>, <condition_variable>, <future>,<mutex>, <ratio>,
 <scoped_allocator>, and <thread>.
```

So in summary:
What are my options to get Visual Express with `<thread>` support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get  support for Visual Studio Express you either need Visual Studio Express 2012, or you can purchase my [Just::Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/order.html) library, which provides the C++11 thread library for MSVC 2005 and later on Windows, and various versions of gcc across Windows, Linux and MacOSX.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized visual studio express 2012 was available :/